# is it possible to view the documentation?

Tags: php, netbeans-6.9

I'd like to know if there is somethings like `Javadoc` but for `PHP`, like the documentation on the official website.

So, for example, if I wrote a function such as `mysql_error`, view on NetBeans [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) kind of documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. PHPDoc.
http://www.phpdoc.org/

Comment: There is Doxygen also. www.doxygen.org